# Flash erase cycles guaranteed

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, flash-memory

My microcontroller (MM32Spin05PT) guarantees 10,000 erase cycles.
Suppose my flash page is already clear, and I re-clear it. So, will number of remaining guaranteed erase cycles reduce?
In other words, I just want to know if I erase a page if it's already clear, will it cause the life of flash memory to reduce?

If yes, I probably have to write a code to check if the flash page has data first, and then only, I must clear it..

Comment: The estimate leans toward the minimum. I would be careful with words like guarantee.  Would expect more than that but not rely on it.  If you perform an erase cycle on the memory whether or not it was erased or not, should count.

Comment: if erased, lets say all ones, if you read all ones it is erased.  And depending on the flash you can write zeros.   at separate times, without an erase, but to make the bits a one you need an erase cycle.   Some though read zeros if erased. and you write ones.

Comment: unless you have something wrong with the memory/interface/power then you can read it to check that it is erased.

Comment: This is really a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. You would probably need to check the flash implementation for your specific part.  I have noted for example if you erase a 128Kb page on an STM32, it takes the specified 800ms or so.  If you erase the page again, it is near instantaneous by comparison, suggesting _possibly_ that the flash-controller does nothing in this case.

Comment: Where are you getting your figure of 10000 cycles?  The datasheet at https://www.mindmotion.com.cn/download/products/DS_MM32SPIN05x_q_EN.pdf says 20000.

Comment: @old_timer : I tend to agree w.r.t. the caution, but the [datasheet for the part][https://www.mindmotion.com.cn/download/products/DS_MM32SPIN05x_q_EN.pdf} uses the term "guaranteed" in the note 1 on endurance at Table 25: "1. _Guaranteed by design, not tested in production._".  As it happens it also has a _minimum_ to 20000 rather than 10000.

Comment: yeah, well as you know that means you should get the 20000, likely an individual part will get many more.  obviously you cant wear out the part in production to test it.  But note there will be some percentage of parts per thousand or per million that will fail to meet those numbers. (just like your mass produced products in general)

Comment: Also please note that these parameters are often specified for -40 to +80 °C. So a serious manufacturer would list the cycles in the case where the product is continuously exposed to the worst case of this temperature range, likely +80. In some cases it also matters how you clock the flash.

Comment: A generic answer may not be valid for all MCUs.  Some documentation for MCUs I use refer to write-erase cycles, implying that there is no cycle unless there is some 'write'.